# Find elements with one element of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a list of elements, each one with one numeric ID and I'm creating a filter to group them

One of the filters has to take the elements that have an ID specified in the array

Such as:

```
var orgsID = [4002,4037];

//Show if it has one of the IDs from the array
$('.event_item[data-id='+orgsID+']').addClass('show-item all');
```

And then go one by one checking whether the LI has that ID. If so, show it

This is the filter:

```
<ul id="e-filters"> 
    <li class="active" id="all">All</li>
    <li id="49504">SU Sports Events</li>
    <li id="4002" class="sportsID">Sports Clubs Events</li>  <!-- Get elements from array -->
</ul>
```

This is the list:

```
<div id="e-list">   
    <div class="event_item" data-id="4219"></div>
    <div class="event_item" data-id="4002"></div>
    <div class="event_item" data-id="5146"></div>
    <div class="event_item" data-id="4037"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: orgsID[number], make it on a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.event_item').filter(function() {
  return jQuery.inArray($(this).data("id"), orgsID) > -1;
}).addClass('show-item all');
```

**Demo**

```js
var orgsID = [4002, 4037];

$('.event_item').filter(function() {
  return jQuery.inArray($(this).data("id"), orgsID) > -1;
}).addClass('show-item all');
```

```css
.show-item{ color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="e-list">
  <div class="event_item" data-id="4219">4219</div>
  <div class="event_item" data-id="4002">4002</div>
  <div class="event_item" data-id="5146">5146</div>
  <div class="event_item" data-id="4037">4037</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop over your array to check if such an element exists.If it exists,add your class.

```
orgsID.forEach(id => {
    if($('.event_item[data-id='+id+']').length){
        $('.event_item[data-id='+orgsID+']').addClass('show-item all');
    }
})
```